# Defining functionally identical models using similar databases in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've got a database with an old schema that I'm going to be migrating data from.  The table names and relationships are identical to the database.  For some reason when I define the models for the old instance, they are acting as though they're the models of the new database.

from_db.rb

```
class FromDB < ActiveRecord::Base
 self.abstract_class = true
 establish_connection FROM_DB
end
```

from_clip.rb

```
class FromClip < FromDB
 self.table_name = "clips"
 belongs_to :clippable, polymorphic: true, counter_cache: true
 belongs_to :video, class_name: "FromVideo"
end
```

clip.rb

```
 class Clip < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :clippable, polymorphic: true, counter_cache: true
   belongs_to :video
 end
```

console

```
FromClip.first.class.name
FromClip Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `clips`.* FROM `clips` LIMIT 1
=> "Clip"
```

All the methods and associations available to FromClip are those in the Clip model rather than the FromClip model, but the instance of FromClip is from the correct database.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

So, it was related to STI.  There are two models that inherit from Clip.  If I use

```
self.inheritance_column = :_non_existing_column
```

in the FromClip model, it works as expected.  I just have to point the clippable method at the right models and make sure I bring over the type column correctly.

```
def clippable
  ("From" + clippable_type).constantize.find_by_id(clippable_id)
end
```